# Is there a way to pause my autoclicker with pyautogui without exiting the full program?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have the following python script that clicks in random coordinates for a web based game. It is a pretty simple script that I have setup a kill on the press of a key. Now due to the nature of the game I have to stop this program roughly every 3 minutes to interact with it. I would love a way to pause/resume the program with a keypress just like I do with exiting the program. I have tried multiple ways and I just keep failing. I would like to avoid threading if at all possible but if that is the only way of doing it then I understand. Here is the code:

import random
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import sys

```
def __init__(self):
    self.run = True

    keyboard.add_hotkey('n', self.stop)

    self.main()

def main(self):
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.01

    multi = (769,395)
    single = (790, 397)
    dex = (780,275)
    intel = (781,296)
    vit = (774,316)
    notank = (132,195)
    tank = (192,193)

    coords = [(327, 200),
              (313, 309),
              (307, 440),
              (439, 440),
              (561, 440),
              (560, 320),
              (428, 322),
              (324, 198),
              (437, 203),
              (587, 222)
              ]
    
    if sys.argv[1] == '1':
        coords.append(dex)
    else:
        coords.append(vit)
    
    if sys.argv[2] == '1':
        coords.append(multi)
    else:
        coords.append(single)
        
    if sys.argv[3] == '1':
        coords.append(notank)
    else:
        coords.append(tank)

    while self.run:
        random.shuffle(coords)

        for x, y in coords:
            pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, 0.01, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
            pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.015)
            if not self.run:
                #break  # exit only `for`-loop (and it will have to check `while self.run`)
                return  # directly exit function `main()` 

def stop(self):
    self.run = False
```

program = Main()

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, program detects 'n' key with "keyboard.add_hotkey()", and when key pressed, program calls stop function and sets run variable, and on the main, it controls run variable and if it is not 'True', returns nothing to exit from init() and program ends with code 0.

You can use keyboard module to detect keypress. I deleted some codes from the code but, full code below:

```
    import pyautogui
    import keyboard
    import sys
    import random
    import
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.01
    stop = False

    multi = (769, 395)
    single = (790, 397)
    dex = (780, 275)
    intel = (781, 296)
    vit = (774, 316)
    notank = (132, 195)
    tank = (192, 193)

    coords = [(327, 200),
              (313, 309),
              (307, 440),
              (439, 440),
              (561, 440),
              (560, 320),
              (428, 322),
              (324, 198),
              (437, 203),
              (587, 222)
              ]

    if sys.argv[1] == '1':
        coords.append(dex)
    else:
        coords.append(vit)

    if sys.argv[2] == '1':
        coords.append(multi)
    else:
        coords.append(single)

    if sys.argv[3] == '1':
        coords.append(notank)
    else:
        coords.append(tank)

    while True:
        random.shuffle(coords)

        for x, y in coords:
            if not stop:
               pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, 0.01, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
               pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.015)
            try: # Don't delete the try except!
               if keyboard.is_pressed("n"): # Quit
                  quit()
               elif keyboard.is_pressed("s"):  # Start/Stop
                  if stop:
                     stop = False
                     print("Started")
                  else:
                     stop = True
                     print("Stopped")
            except:
                continue
```

But code gives error on my pc :(((